# transaction timestamp for React.js app that display name and value in columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am very new to react and I am designing a 3 page app that gathers choices and values from page 1 and 2 and shows total choices on page 3. I have complete the items chosen and the values but I would like to add a timestamp when you get to page 3 with the third columns. I have used  and facets.name and facets.value but I am stumped on how to display a timestamp for the current moment those choices appear on page 3.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where are you getting the timestamp from? A back-end?

Comment: If you only need a timestamp at which point page 3 was entered, why not create one when the page 3 component is mounted? `const YourPage3Component = () => { const [timestamp] = useState(new Date()); /* tadaa, here's your timestamp! */ /* ... rest of your code ... */ };`